# Potential Logging/Log4j Clobbering Situation

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, logging, log4j

I have two webapps deployed to Tomcat.  The service is started with -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties in catalina.sh

At times I'm noticing that only one of the webapps is logging to the file.  I restart Tomcat and both are logging again.  Any ideas on what the conflict might be?  Shouldn't this be a supported configuration since both apps are running in the same JVM, with a global configuration?

The only thing I can think of that might be interfering is the CXF log config: META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger

**update**

I found that both webapps are still logging, but one webapp is logging to a different position in the file, so I'll see something like

```
1:59PM - xx
2:00PM - xxxx
1:45PM - xxx
```

etc.

Sometimes it will be logging to a rolled file.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this happens, but you can insert some debugging code being triggered to see what's going on when logging fails. Something like this (code untested!):

```
Category logger = Logger.getLogger(yourClass);
do {
  Level level = logger.getLevel();
  System.out.println("Log level of " + logger + " is " + level + ". Appenders:");
  for (Enumeration appenders = logger.getAllAppenders() ; appenders.hasMoreElements() ;) {
    System.out.println(appenders.nextElement());
  }
  logger = logger.getParent();
} while (logger != Logger.getRootLogger())
```

It is somewhat ironic to debug log4j with `System.out.println`, but it would do the job (it's a throw-away code anyway).